# Grupo en reportviewer y numeracion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Tengo dos inconvenientes.

El primero es como agrupar unas filas en mi reporte.

Este el diseño del reporte
[image: Diseño reporte]

Y este es el resultado cuando genero el reporte.
[image: Resultado reporte]

Acá necesito hacer la forma de que las dos filas que se repiten agruparlas.

Y la otra pregunta seria, como numerar las filas. Tengo entendido que para numerar utilizo la siguiente expresión

```
=RowNumber(Nothing)
```

Ese seria para la primera fila, pero quiero que de ahí en adelante que siga así:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
...
```

Comment: Me imagino que rellenas tus reportes mediante consultas a base de datos verdad?

Comment: @TwoDent Si, tengo un dataset donde estan agregados los store procedure que utilizo para los reportes.

Comment: Sugiero que muestres tu codigo para una mejor solucion @Norcade

Comment: Te recomendaria que "agrupes" lo mas cerca de los datos posible, es decir que lo hagas en la consulta (procedimiento almacenado) que utiliza dicho reporte. Porque imaginate estas enviando al reporte o obteniendo de la DB varias filas que no la visualizas y eso hace lento en grandes request de usuarios.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí hay dos ejemplos de como agrupar:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bno0pCsTHok
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_87Jdk8dxs

Te tienes que asegurar que debes hacer la agrupación dentro(inside) del grupo.
Para hacer el conteo, puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
=CountRows("NombredelaColumna")
```

o

```
=CountRows("NombredelGrupoporcategoria"),
```

sintaxis:

```
CountRows(scope, recursive) ,
```

Tambien puedes probar así:

```
Count(Fields!AnyFieldNameInDataSet1.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Referencia:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f937674-a822-4c4f-9e23-6678c92c1738/report-viewer-rows-count-for-a-query-results?forum=vbgeneral